# models using controllers?

Tags: php

is it usual to use controllers in models?

then you have to include the controller in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Models should not be using controllers.

To clarify, using the MVC pattern, the user communicates with the *controller* which manipulates the *model* which dispatches its results to the *view* back to the user.

[image]

Image taken from [**The Model-View-Controller (MVC) Design Pattern for PHP**](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/model-view-controller.html#together)

#### Update to Doug's response:

> The most logical way to explain how the components work is by starting from the model, then going through the controller, and finally reaching the view. And "MCV" would not have been nearly as appealing a name to the ear as "MVC."

Taken from Chapter 1 of *Beginning ASP.NET MVC 1.0* by Simone Chiaretta and Keyvan Nayyeri.

Comment: so then its a CMV pattern, :) I never understand why M comes first.

Comment: I read somewhere reason being is that its something along the lines of that it is easier phonetically to pronounce *MVC* than *CMV*. If I can find the actual reference, I'll try to remember it.

Comment: couldnt it be user to controller to model and back to controller which insert the data from the model to an appropiate view?

Answer (score 2):

No it is not common. You should *never* have to use your controllers from your model.

If you feel the need to, it probably means code that is currently in your controller should live in a shared library, or actually be in the model to begin with.

It is of course proper to use a model from a controller.

**Update**

Code that doesn't directly relate to a specific database table/record (model), or doesn't directly respond to a user's action (controller), would be a good candidate for a utilities or library file.

This is more normal, and where you load it depends on if you are using a framework or not. If it just your custom app, you can just do a `require_once` in your model and use the utility methods from there.

Comment: but what if i want to log things within a model (errors and so on) and i got a utilities class as a controller with a log method?

Comment: am i mixing up a controller with a class? could you call classes (utilities, validations) from a model?

Comment: Controllers are classes, you can have a controller class for handling exceptions and logging.

Comment: but i think controllers are the redirectors (models -> views) and not handling logging and exceptions. that will be other classes which arent controllers. am i right guys? so in models you can use classes for eg. validations and logging?

Comment: @noname that is correct, utility functions and logging would not be a controller.

Comment: $doug: so i can use helper classes in models?

Comment: Yes. It makes sense to have shared helpers available outside of a single model (and of course included in them as needed).